# login button redirecting to a different page

Tags: html, redirect

ok so im working on a website for a friend and she is wanting a login that when they login and if the information is correct it will redirect them to that page and only members could see that page. so far this is the what i have.

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: auto; max-width: 480px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #0361A8; border- radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #0361A8; margin: 50px auto auto;">
    <div style="background: #0361A8; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 15px;"><span style="font-family: verdana,arial; color: #D4D4D4; font-size: 1.00em; font-weight:bold;">Login to Members Section</span></div>
    <div style="background: ; padding: 15px">
    <style type="text/css" scoped="">
    td { text-align:left; font-family: verdana,arial; color: #064073; font-size: 1.00em; }
    input { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius: 5px; color: #666666; display: inline-block; font-size: 1.00em;  padding: 5px; width: 100%; }
    input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] { height: auto; width: auto; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #0361A8; float: right; text-align:right; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:7px;}
    table.center { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
    .error { font-family: verdana,arial; color: #D41313; font-size: 1.00em; }
    </style>
    <form method="post" action="http://www.authpro.com/auth/deluxe/"  name="aform" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="hide" value="">
    <table class='center'>
    <tr><td>Login:</td><td><input type="text" name="login"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td> </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Lost your username or password? Find it <a href="http://www.authpro.com/auth/userproject/?action=lost">here</a>!</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Not member yet? Click <a href="http://www.authpro.com/auth/userproject/?action=reg">here</a> to register. </td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div></div></div>
```

Comment: and whats your problem? i dont see anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

every thing is working like it should.  The script that is run when you press the login but is what will redirect you

Comment: Im trying to get it to where when they log in they are redirected to a certain page that can only be seen and used after login.

Comment: You can do all of that in PHP and MySQL.  This should get you started http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html